# Camera in Phonegap 2.9.0 not working

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins

I'm using PhoneGap 2.9.0 with the Camera API for my iPhone application. When I call the method it's not working. Here my code:

**App/Supporting Files/Cordova.plist**

```
<key>Plugins</key>
<dict>
<key>Camera</key>
<string>CDVCamera</string>
</dict>
```

**config.xml**

```
<plugin name="Camera" value="CDVCamera" />
```

**On capture method**

```
function capturePhoto() {
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, fail, {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
});
}
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
Ext.Viewport.setMasked({
    xtype: 'loadmask',
    message: 'Loading..',
    indicator: true
});
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

var params = new Object();
params.value1 = "Fastabuy";
options.params = params;
options.chunkedMode = false;

var URL = imguploadurl + 'pid=&type=single';
//console.log(URL);
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, URL, win, fail, options);
/*attendphoto=imageURI;         
             document.getElementById('productpic').src = attendphoto; 
             App.gvars.Productimg=attendphoto;  
             //console.log( App.gvars.Productimg);*/
 }


var captureSuccess = function (mediaFiles) {
for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    fpath = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
    fimage = mediaFiles[i].name;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotimg, fail);
}
};
```

I don't know whats wrong with my code. Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "it's not working"? What exactly is the error?

Comment: @AndrewLively its not opening the gallery , or camera. when i click

Comment: @Fazil Hey, Have you the solution? Plz help me its very urgent for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are referencing the new phonegap/cordova.js file in `index.html` e.g.
`<script src="phonegap.js"></script>`
It gets put in the same directory as the index.html when the app is built e.g.

- www\
- -- index.html
- -- phonegap.js
- -- img\
- -- css\
- -- js\
- ...